# How to I combine 2 curve points to create a mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to combine these two end points of curve so I could create a whole new mesh;

which would look like a platform with a curve and whole faces.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want a plane the same shape as your current mesh:
[image]

In Edit mode, select Edge mode. Click one edge and shift-click the opposite one to create the outer edge. 'P' to separate the selection then go back to Object mode, select the edge, and back to Edit mode. 'A' to select all and 'F' to Fill. You then have a plane the shape of your original object.

Comment: Thanks for answering bro.. but actually I'm using a bezier curve and I've set an array to a cube so it would follow the curve.  So basically I can't select the edge option just like what you did

Comment: In future please add information like that to your question to stop people wasting their time!